# GridGain distribute Tasks according to CPU Numbers of Nodes available in Projection

Tags: java, distributed-computing, gridgain

I wrote a very simple Java application that does some md5 hash computations.
I'm trying to distribute this computations to several nodes within my lab to speed things up.
This actually DOES WORK, but HOW its distributed is causing me troubles.
There are nodes within the grid that have 8 cpus and nodes that only have one.
I'd like to assign one job(thread, callable, task) per cpu per node. But I get a very bad distribution: sometimes 4 jobs run on a node with one cpu, and a node that has 8 cpus gets only 2 or 3 tasks.
I found the forPredicate(GridPredicate p) Function in the GridGain API([forPredicate in GridGain API](http://www.gridgain.com/api/javadoc/org/gridgain/grid/GridProjection.html#forPredicate%28org.gridgain.grid.lang.GridPredicate%29)):

> Creates a grid projection which includes all nodes that pass the given predicate filter.

However, I'm using it wrong, or I got it's function wrong. Here is a minimal example of what I got:

```
       public class Driver implements GridCallable<Integer>{
        [...]                    
        Grid g = GridGain.start(gConf);    
        ArrayList<GridFuture<Integer>> workers = new ArrayList<GridFuture<Integer>>();
        for(int i=0; i<workercount; i++){
            Driver worker = new Driver();
            //Here some values get added to the driver object, irrelevant
            workers.add(g.forPredicate(new GridPredicate<GridNode>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(GridNode node) {
                        int cores = node.metrics().getTotalCpus();
                        return ((node.metrics().getCurrentWaitingJobs()+node.metrics().getCurrentActiveJobs()) < cores);
                    }
            }).compute().call(worker));
        }
        [...]
        public Integer call(){[...]}
        }
```

The expected behaviour was that it checks every node how much cpus it's got and check if the jobcount(active and waiting) is greater than this number before sending a job to it.
But, it's not. I still get a "bad distribution".
Can anyone tell me how to distribute according to available cpu numbers per node?
Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using metrics for relatively short-running tasks usually does not work well because metrics update frequency is too small.

I see two solutions available out-of-the box:

- Configure `GridWeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi` with node weight equal to number of available processors and execute you task on grid without selecting subprojection, letting GridGain to load-balance the task. Then nodes will get load proportional to the number of processors available.
- Configure `GridJobStealingCollisionSpi`. In this case underloaded nodes will 'steal' jobs from overloaded nodes with jobs waiting in the queue. This approach works especially well when job computation cost is not known in advance.

Refer to SPIs javadoc and documentation for more information:
http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Job+Collision+Resolution
http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Load+Balancing

UPD: here is how you can configure weighted load balancing SPI to use number of available processors:

```
<property name="loadBalancingSpi">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.loadbalancing.weightedrandom.GridWeightedRandomLoadBalancingSpi">
        <property name="useWeights" value="true"/>
        <property name="nodeWeight" value="#{T(java.lang.Runtime).getRuntime().availableProcessors()}"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```